# Are the powers of the maximal ideal in the local Noetherian ring of formal power series in $n$ variables free modules

Tags: power-series, homological-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, free-modules

Let $\mathbb C[[t_1, \dots, t_n]]$ be the ring of formal power series in $n$ indeterminates. Let $\mathfrak{m}=(t_1, ..., t_n)$ be the maximal ideal in $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$. Is $\mathfrak{m}^p$ a free module? By definition, $\mathfrak{m}^p=\{\sum_{i_1+\dotsi_n=p}a_{i_1\dots i_n}t_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}: a_{i_1\dots i_n}\in\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]\}$, but is it true that this is isomorphic to the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i_1+...+i_n=p}\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]t_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}$? I think so as, the generators $t_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$.

Comment: The generators are not linearly independent. For example, $t_2 \cdot t_1 - t_1 \cdot t_2=0$. Of course, when $n=1$ your claim holds.

Comment: In fact, an ideal is a free module if and only if it is a principal ideal. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049455/if-ideal-i-of-domain-r-is-free-r-module-then-i-is-principal-ideal

Comment: Thank you for this eye-opening comment. For $n\geq1$, can we write $\mathfrak{m}^p=\prod_{i_1+\dots+i_n\geq p}\mathbb Ct_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}$. As this is an infinite product, it is indeed not free.

Comment: Your reasoning is faulty. That is an equality of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces, but you're interested in the $\mathbb{C}[[t_1,\dots,t_n]]$-module structure. The argument given in the answer I linked above (the one for integral domains) is the natural way to disprove freeness, I think. The point is that the module can't have more than one generator, because $b\cdot a - a\cdot b=0$.

Comment: Still, you can give $\prod_{i_1+...+i_n\geq p}\mathbb Ct_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}$ the structure of a $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-module using the isomorphism of $\mathbb C$-vector spaces $\mathfrak{m}^p\cong\prod_{i_1+...+i_n\geq p}\mathbb  Ct_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}$. This turns the isomorphism of complex vector spaces into an isomorphism of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules.

Comment: No, because as a $\mathbb{C}[[t_1,\dots,t_n]]$-module, $\mathfrak{m}^p$ is not a direct product like that. The factors $\mathbb{C}t_1^{i_1}\dots t_{n}^{i_n}$ are not $\mathbb{C}[[t_1,\dots,t_n]]$-submodules, so what you write is not a direct product of $\mathbb{C}[[t_1,\dots,t_n]]$-modules. Hence your argument in the comment above does not apply.

Comment: That is correct. $\mathfrak{m}^p$ is indeed not a direct product of $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-submodules, but as a whole, $\prod_{i_1+...i_n\geq p}\mathbb Ct_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}$ can be given the structure of a $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-module such that $\mathfrak{m}^p\cong\prod_{i_1+...i_n\geq p}\mathbb Ct_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}$ as $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules, can't it?

Comment: Yes, that is automatically true because they are already isomorphic as vector spaces (and there, indeed, the product notation makes sense). But when you are considering the objects as modules over the power series ring, it is sloppy to use the $\prod$ notation to denote something other than a direct product of such modules. Indeed, in a previous comment you seem to have mistaken the product representation as a product of modules ("As this is an infinite product, it is indeed not free").

Comment: Yes, it is sloppy, indeed. Indeed, I have conflated freeness over $\mathbb C$ and freeness over $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$. I was not precise at all what I was writing about.

Comment: @Douglas Molin, If we had something like $M[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$ for a $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-module $M$, is it true that $M[[t_1, ..., t_n]]\cong M$ as $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$-modules?

Comment: What is $M[[t_1,\dots,t_n]]$? Also, would you like me to compile my comments into an answer below that you can accept?

Comment: Yes, if you compile your comments as an answer, I will accept it. Well, it is the space of all formal linear combinations $\sum_{i_1+\dots+i_n\geq0}m_{i_1\dots i_n}t_1^{i_1}\cdots t_n^{i_n}$ with $m_{i_1\dots i_n}\in M$. If you want to split it as a tensor product, probably it would be something along the lines of  $M\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C} \mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, except in the trivial case $n=1$. The reason why the direct sum decomposition does not hold is the generating monomials are *not* linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}[[t_1,\dots,t_n]]$. For example, $t_1$ and $t_2$ are linearly dependent because $$t_2\cdot t_1 - t_1\cdot t_2=0.$$
More generally, any two elements $f,g\in\mathfrak{m}^p$ are linearly dependent for the same reason, which proves that the ideal is not a free module (in the $n\geq 2$ case).

In fact, an ideal is a free module if and only if it is principal, see [If ideal $I$ of domain $R$ is free $R$-module, then $I$ is principal ideal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049455/if-ideal-i-of-domain-r-is-free-r-module-then-i-is-principal-ideal).